# Pandas fill column with string.split() from different column based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

What I want to achieve can be seen in the following tables:

[image]

So, the idea is to only fill column `lag_id` if column `Port` includes string `Lag`. If so, I shall split such string, keep the number and insert it into the desired column.

In order to achieve that, I tried the following:

```
df['lag_id'] = df[df['Port'].str.contains('Lag')]['Port'].apply(lambda s:s.split(' ')[1])
```

That will partially do the job. I do get string splitting, but the rest of the column `lag_id` is being emptied.

[image]

Ideas on how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
mask = df['Port'].str.startswith('Lag')
df.loc[mask, 'lag_id'] = df.loc[mask, 'Port'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[1]))
df['lag_id'] = df['lag_id'].astype(int)

#       Port  lag_id
# 0    3/2/1      10
# 1    3/2/2      10
# 2    3/2/3      10
# 3    3/2/4      10
# 4    Lag 1       1
# 5   Lag 10      10
# 6   Lag 10      10
# 7   Lag 10      10
# 8   Lag 10      10
# 9    Lag 2       2
# 10   Lag 3       3
```

Comment: Great! I see what you did with `mask`. Neat. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a combination of `pd.Series.str.extract` and `pd.Series.fillna`

```
df.assign(lag_id=df.Port.str.extract('Lag (\d+)', expand=False).fillna(df.lag_id))

      Port lag_id
0    3/2/1     10
1    3/2/2     10
2    3/2/3     10
3    3/2/4     10
4    Lag 1      1
5   Lag 10     10
6   Lag 10     10
7   Lag 10     10
8   Lag 10     10
9    Lag 2      2
10   Lag 3      3
```